# An easy computation of an integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a question about an integral. I don't know how to quick compute $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(x,1)|x|^2dx$$where$$\phi(x,1)=(4\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-|x|^2/4}$$
which is the fundamental solution of heat equation with time t=1. I wonder if there is some way not that nasty to compute it? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$J=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2) e^{-\|x\|^2/4}\,d\mu = n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}x_1^2 e^{-x_1^2/4}e^{-(x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2)/4}\,d\mu $$
by symmetry. Since $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2/4}\,dx = 4\sqrt{\pi}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/4}\,dx = 2\sqrt{\pi}$, by Fubini's theorem it follows that:
$$ (4\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|x\|^2 e^{-\|x\|^2/4}\,d\mu = (4\pi)^{-n/2}\cdot 2n\cdot (4\pi)^{n/2}=\color{red}{2n}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That's so quick and easy to compute it!

Comment: @R.T: you're welcome.